# How can I add a question from another class?

Tags: swift

At the moment I'm programming a little Truth or Dare game. The player should be able to add his own questions.

I'm a complete beginner and I'm still learning the basics.

This is my class which contains the questions:

```
class QuestionBankFun {
   var questionListFun = [Question]()
   init() {
      let question1 = Question(text: "QUESTION")
      questionListFun.append(question1)
   }
}
```

This is my Button which should add the Question (It's in another class):

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

//HERE THE QUESTION SHOULD BE ADDED TO THE QuestionListFun(TextField is used)

   if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TruthOrDarePickerViewController") as? TruthOrDarePickerViewController {
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create an instance of QuestionBankFun class and also a method for add question not in initializer. the code should be like this:

```
let questionBankFun = QuestionBankFun()
questionBankFun.addQuestion("QUESTION")
```

in question class like this:

```
class QuestionBankFun {

   var questionListFun = [Question]()
   public func addQuestion(String question) {
       let question1 = Question(text: "QUESTION")
       questionListFun.append(question1)
   }

}
```